# How to emulate file opened in text mode in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking into ways of testing some code that acts on files, but I would like to write some tests that only rely on specific strings within the source file rather than having a specific file somewhere in the file system.

I know that it is possible to provide a `file`-like stream interface to strings via `io.StringIO`.

The problem is that the operations do not follow the same semantic.
For example, a combination of `file.seek()` and `file.read()` would produce different results depending on whether the file object comes from `open()` or from `io.StringIO` for strings containing non-ASCII characters:

```
import io

#      'abgdezhjiklmnxoprstufqyw'
text = 'αβγδεζηθικλμνξoπρστυφχψω'


with open('test.txt', 'w') as file_obj:
    file_obj.write(text)


with open('test.txt', 'r') as file_obj:
    file_obj.seek(8)
    print(file_obj.read(8))
# εζηθικλμ


with io.StringIO(text) as file_obj:
    file_obj.seek(8)
    print(file_obj.read(8))
# ικλμνξoπ
```

The issue does not appear for ASCII-only strings:

```
import io

text = 'abgdezhjiklmnxoprstufqyw'


with open('test.txt', 'w') as file_obj:
    file_obj.write(text)


with open('test.txt', 'r') as file_obj:
    file_obj.seek(8)
    print(file_obj.read(8))
# iklmnxop


with io.StringIO(text) as file_obj:
    file_obj.seek(8)
    print(file_obj.read(8))
# iklmnxop
```

Obviously, this is due to `.seek()` following a `bytes` semantic for the `offset` parameter in the case of files opened with `open()`, while for `io.StringIO` it follows a `str` semantic.

I do understand that for performance reasons it is not practical to have a `seek()` following `str` semantic, not even if the file is opened in text mode.

Hence, my question is: how do I get an equivalent `io.StringIO()` with a `seek` method following the `bytes` semantic? Do I have to override `io.StringIO` myself or there is a better approach?

Comment: Doing `seek(8)` on a TextIO file leads to undefined behaviour. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.seek So you really shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: I would say, if you want to test your code, you can write to `/tmp/` directory. No need to search for complex solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#shelve.BytesIO) and [`TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) to emulate the behavior of a real file:

```
text = 'αβγδεζηθικλμνξoπρστυφχψω'

with io.BytesIO(text.encode('utf8')) as binary_file:
    with io.TextIOWrapper(binary_file, encoding='utf8') as file_obj:
        file_obj.seek(8)
        print(file_obj.read(8))
        # εζηθικλμ
```

Comment: Thanks! That is precisely what I was looking for. Note that you could also have this with a single `with` block. It is also worth mentioning that the `encoding` parameter is optional, like with `open()`.

Comment: The encoding is not optional because `str.encode` defaults to a different encoding than `TextIOWrapper` (`'utf-8'` vs `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) instead:

```
import io

s = "αβγδεζηθικλμνξoπρστυφχψω"
with io.BytesIO(s.encode("utf-8")) as f:
    f.seek(8)
    print(f.read(8).decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: this will output `εζηθ` instead of `εζηθικλμ `

Comment: @RomanPerekhrestm, yes, it should print `εζηθ`, cause it's 8 bytes.

Comment: Depending on the actual data, this may not work so well, since UTF-8 encodes a char using 1 to 4 bytes.

Comment: @PM2Ring, standart `TextIO` read utf-8 string well, but as I understood author need smth different.

Answer (score 0):

There is a respective [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) as stream implementation for bytes buffer.

But, manipulating a file with **unicode** text in `text` mode like this

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file_obj:
    file_obj.seek(8)
    print(file_obj.read(8))  # εζηθικλμ
```

will read 8 chars not bytes.
To extract the same text fragment from bytes buffer you need to provision a length of byte sequence beforehand:

```
with open(dir_path + 'test.txt', 'r') as file_obj:
    file_obj.seek(8)
    text_part = file_obj.read(8)
    byte_len = len(text_part.encode('utf8'))
    print(byte_len)   # 16
    print(text_part)  # εζηθικλμ 


with io.BytesIO(bytes(text.encode('utf8'))) as file_obj:
    file_obj.seek(8)
    print(file_obj.read(byte_len).decode(encoding='utf8'))  # εζηθικλμ
```

Otherwise you may get an "unexpected" text fragment:

```
with io.BytesIO(bytes(text.encode('utf8'))) as file_obj:
    file_obj.seek(8)
    print(file_obj.read(8).decode(encoding='utf8'))  # εζηθ
```

Comment: Please see the docs I linked in my comment on the question. Calling `seek` on a TextIO file invokes undefined behaviour unless the arg is a value returned be `tell`